# Route from Incoming ASPX url to an ASP.NET MVC Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a url Review.aspx?reviewId=3 and I'd like to have this url be routed to an MVC controller/action Review/3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, a simple route like this worked:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
          "Reviews_Old", // Route name
          "LOreview.aspx", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "LOReview", action = "Review", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

And the query string parameters are model bound on the controller action parameters