# Page not found error default.aspx when trying to redirect to action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My MVC application does not have a page called default.aspx

I am trying to implement something that looks at a request URL and if it contains default.aspx, redirect it

```html
public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            var request = HttpContext.Request;
            var uri = request.Url;
            if (uri != null)
            {
                if (uri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/?") || uri.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("/default.aspx?"))
                {
                    var newUri = RedirectWithParametersHelper.DetermineFinalUri(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
                    return RedirectPermanent(newUri);
                }
            }

            var model = new SearchResponse();
            return View(model);
        }
```

This doesnt get called for the URL /default.aspx?parameter=1

So I get a page not found error

Can anyone help please?

Paul

Comment: Try this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590662/route-from-incoming-aspx-url-to-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action`

Comment: I have added this and can see that the route is being added but I still get the error?  Even if I Actually create an empty page called default.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to define a Route which is not like your ActionResult Method, then you should define your Route in RouteConfig.

Otherwise you have the Option to add

```
[Route("{default.aspx}")]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close to the solution.  In case anyone else gets this you need to do [System.Web.Mvc.Route("default.aspx")] - Removing /.  Also routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); must be in the route.config BEFORE routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",.... @daniel, could you modify your answer please?